Expression for stiffness matrix of discontinuous problem
I have a finite element problem of two subdomains coupled at their shared interface. For simplicity, assume the domain is a line interval $0<x<1$ with interface at $x=0.5$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that the domain is subdivided into 10 equal elements such that $h=0.1$.
The problem we seek to solve is
\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot (\nabla u) = 0
\end{equation}
where $u|_{\Omega_0}=u^{(0)}$ and $u|_{\Omega_1}=u^{(1)}$. We apply a dirichlet bc such that $u(x=0) = 0$ and $u(x=1)=1$.
The variational formulation in each subdomain is
\begin{equation}
F_0 = \int_{\Omega_0} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \mathrm{dx} - \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Gamma_X}(\nabla u^{(0)} + \nabla u^{(1)})\cdot n^{(0)} v^{(0)}\mathrm{dS} - \int_{\Gamma_X}\nabla v^{(0)} \cdot \pmb{n}^{(0)}(u^{(1)}-u^{(0)})\mathrm{dS} + \frac{\gamma}{h}\int_{\Gamma_X}(u^{(1)}-u^{(0)})\pmb{n}^{(0)}v^{(0)}\mathrm{dS}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
F_1 = \int_{\Omega_1} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v \mathrm{dx} - \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Gamma_X}(\nabla u^{(0)} + \nabla u^{(1)})\cdot n^{(1)} v^{(1)}\mathrm{dS} - \int_{\Gamma_X}\nabla v^{(1)} \cdot \pmb{n}^{(0)}(u^{(1)}-u^{(0)})\mathrm{dS} + \frac{\gamma}{h}\int_{\Gamma_X}(u^{(1)}-u^{(0)})\pmb{n}^{(1)}v^{(1)}\mathrm{dS}
\end{equation}
where $\gamma \in\mathbb{R}^+$ is a penalty term (which I set to $\gamma = 15$) and $u^{(1)}-u^{(0)}$ is the jump of $u$ and $\frac{1}{2}(\nabla u^{(0)}+ \nabla u^{(1)})$ is the average flux.
Think of $\Gamma_X$ as the shared interface.
I used a finite element software with piecewise linear basis functions, and it gives me the Jacobian of the stiffness matrix.
Because of the discontinuity at $x=0.5$, we have 12 degrees of freedom for 10 elements and piecewise linear basis functions.
$J = \frac{1}{h}
\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & -1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
   -1 & 2 & -1 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & & \\
     & -1 & 2 & -1 & & & & & & & & & \\
     & & -1 & 2 & -1 & & & & & & & \\
     & & & -1 & 2-\gamma & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \gamma & & & & \\
     & & & & -\gamma h & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & & & & \\
     & & & & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 1 & -\gamma h& & & & \\
     & & & & \gamma & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 2-\gamma & -1 & & & \\
     & & & & & & & -1 & 2 & -1 & & \\
     & & & & & & & & -1 & 2 & -1 & \\
     & & & & & & & & & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
     & & & & & & & & & & -1 & 1 \\
  \end{bmatrix}$
I don't understand how the values in rows 5 to 8 are derived, since the integration is over the interface and the basis functions that would have a value of 1 at the interface are those for nodes at the interface.
